# Call to a member function fetchObject() while using sqlite

Tags: java, php, android, sqlite, server

I'm trying to check from the server if the user is registered or not here is my php code :

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
$dir = 'sqlite:/mumble-server.sqlite';
$dbh  = new PDO($dir) or die("cannot open the database");

if ($_POST['func'] == 1) {
$mobileUser = $_POST['phone'];
$res_list = "SELECT count(*) FROM appusers WHERE phone ='" . $mobileUser . "'";
$rock = $dbh->query($res_list);
while ($obj = $rock->fetchObject()) {
    $listing[] = $obj;
}
echo json_encode(array('reslogin' => $listing));
}
```

and here is my client side (java) code :

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.2.26/SqliteTest/sqlite.php");
  try {
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("func", "1"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone", "09367701739"));
    Log.e("mainToPost", "mainToPost" + nameValuePairs.toString());
    UrlEncodedFormEntity form;
    form = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,"UTF-8");
    httppost.setEntity(form);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
    MainActivity.InputStreamToStringExample str = new MainActivity.InputStreamToStringExample();
    responseLogin = str.getStringFromInputStream(inputStream);
    Log.e("response", "response -----" + responseLogin);
    jsonresponse = new JSONObject(responseLogin);
    responsemain = jsonresponse.toString();

  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return null;
```

but I'm getting this response from the server :

```
response -----<br /><b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetchObject() on boolean in W:\xampp\htdocs\SqliteTest\sqlite.php:16Stack trace:#0 {main}  thrown in <b>W:\xampp\htdocs\SqliteTest\sqlite.php</b> on line <b>16</b><br />
```

and line 16 is `while ($obj = $rock->fetchObject()) {`
does anyone know how can I fix this?

---

I changed my PHP to

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
$dir = 'sqlite:/mumble-server.sqlite';
$dbh  = new PDO($dir) or die("cannot open the database");
if ($_POST['func'] == 1) {
$mobileUser = $_POST['phone'];
$rock = $dbh->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM appusers WHERE phone ='" . $mobileUser . "'");
$result = $rock->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode(array('reslogin' => $result));
}
```

but now this error is appearing :

```
response -----<br /><b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on boolean in W:\xampp\htdocs\SqliteTest\sqlite.php:8Stack trace:#0 {main}  thrown in <b>W:\xampp\htdocs\SqliteTest\sqlite.php</b> on line <b>8</b><br />
```

Comment: From PDO `query` manual: "PDO::query() returns a PDOStatement object, or FALSE on failure." So, your query __failed__

Comment: Query: Error says line 16 but your code only has 14 line ??? Are you sure this is the right code fragment??

Comment: I just deleted commented codes when i was posing question

Comment: @u_mulder thanks for your comment sorry I'm new in PHP can you tell me what code I should use to fix this?